# When to introduce platform-specific versions of Portable Class Libraries?

Tags: .net, nuget, portable-class-library

I recently released a NuGet package that targets PCL (only) and has dependencies on Microsoft.Bcl.Async, Microsoft.Net.Http, and PCLStorage. For argument's sake, let's assume that the largest group of potential users are targeting .NET 4.5 (probably valid), which supports the functionality provided by all 3 of those dependencies natively. So these users are effectively being forced to download and install unnecessary packages.

I've been unable to find specific guidance from Microsoft or elsewhere as to when or if it is appropriate to introduce platform-specific builds in addition to a PCL build in NuGet packages. Is there specific guidance or rules of thumb? Although PCL-only achieves maximum portability and eases some development pains, is it considered bad practice to force unnecessary libraries on the majority in order to provide maximum portability to the minority?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see how .net 4.5 covers PCLStorage functionality?

Comment: @Dan System.IO has everything I need on any full version of the framework.